# How to support microsoft media player seekingin a Video Streaming server?

Tags: c#, streaming, dlna

I implemented a DLNA media player server function.

The server supports seeking function for DMP(Digital Media Player) and XBMC or VLC player works correctly.

But when I played video in Microsoft Media Player and try to seek to later time position,the media player stopped.

I had analyzed network packets of  MS Media player and tried to create same header as DMS(Digital Media Server) of MS Media Player.

But I still failed.

Is there any important tag info I missed?

My response code about response is as following:

```
NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(mClient.Client);
try
{

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);
    if (rangeBegin >= 1)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 {0}", HttpStatus.Http206);
    }
    else
    {
        sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 {0}", HttpStatus.Http200);
    }


    long k=total_size - rangeBegin;
    sw.WriteLine("Content-Length: {0}",k );
    sw.WriteLine("Content-Type: " + ContentType);
    try
    {
        String st = HttpRequest.IfUnmodifiedSince;
        sw.WriteLine("LAST-MODIFIED: " + st);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log(TAG, "Exception:" + e.Message);
    }

    sw.WriteLine("Server: PegaServer");
    sw.WriteLine("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    //sw.WriteLine("ContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: DLNA.ORG_PN=AVC_MP4_HP_HD_AAC;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01500000000000000000000000000000");
    sw.WriteLine("contentFeatures.dlna.org: DLNA.ORG_PN=AVC_MP4_HP_HD_AAC;DLNA.ORG_OP=01;DLNA.ORG_CI=0;DLNA.ORG_FLAGS=01700000000000000000000000000000");
    sw.WriteLine("CONTENT-RANGE: bytes " + getContentRange());
    sw.WriteLine("transferMode.dlna.org: Streaming");
    String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("r");
    sw.WriteLine("Date: " + date);

    sw.WriteLine("Pragma: no-cache");
    sw.WriteLine("Expires:  0");
    sw.WriteLine("Cache-Control:    no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform, private");
    sw.WriteLine("Connection: close");
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion for the media seek request?

Comment: Post the request and response as captured on the network.

Comment: Jay, you've got some problems with this code. 1) The `NetworkStream` and `StreamWriter` both need to be in `using` blocks, so they get cleaned up even if an exception happens. 2) Don't log exceptions every time they happen. Log them at a higher level of your application. 3) After the exception, since you don't know what the exception was, **do not continue**. If you insist on logging exceptions in every try/catch block (very bad idea), then put a `throw;` statement at the end of the catch.